# Google Drive API via Service Account - access_denied on one domain, other calls/domains work fine

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I have a set of WordPress plugins, written in PHP using the latest Google PHP Client library.

They use Service Accounts to obtain a list of Drive files, and (separately) a list of Google Groups for a user via the Admin SDK.

All my customers are led through the process of setting up a project in Google Cloud Console, creating a Service Account, and setting domain-wide delegation for the relevant scopes (https //www.googleapis.com/auth/drive and https //www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly). They also input the email address of an admin user to act as 'sub' in the API calls.

For most customers, this all works fine.

But for just a couple of customers, we face 'access_denied' problems with the Drive API call - Google support have even verified themselves that the domain-wide delegation all seems to be set up correctly, and suggested posting here.

Using the PHP client library (1.0.5-beta), we make two calls using the Service Account.

The first call works:

```
$serviceclient = new Google_Client();
$groupservice = new Google_Service_Directory($serviceclient);
$groupservice->groups->listGroups(Array('userKey' => '<long google numeric id for any user>', 'pageToken' => ''));
```

This is equivalent to GET /admin/directory/v1/groups?userKey=&pageToken=

We see good results - a JSON list of the user's Groups.

However, when we try to make a call to Drive API through the Service Account, we don't seem to be authorized:

```
$serviceclient = new Google_Client();
$params = array('q' => "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'root' in parents and trashed = false");
$driveservice = new Google_Service_Drive($serviceclient);
$obj = $driveservice->files->listFiles($params);
```

Equivalent to GET /drive/v2/files?q=%27root%27+in+parents+and+trashed+%3D+false+and+mimeType+%3D+%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27

In this case we see a 403 forbidden response when the PHP client library attempts to refresh the OAuth token:
{
  "error" : "access_denied",
  "error_description" : "Requested client not authorized."
}

The error clearly happens at the token refresh stage POST to accounts.google.com /o/oauth2/token

Our Curl debugging shows that this is returned as follows for the Admin API scope:
{
  "access_token" : "",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
}

For the Drive API we get:
{
  "error" : "access_denied",
  "error_description" : "Requested client not authorized."
}

Does anyone else have any known problems with Drive API over Service Account like this?

Comment: Have these "forbidden" domains admins check the check mark for "Allow users to install Google Drive apps" in the Admin Console?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We have also found this to cause a problem in the past. I thought we had tried checking some of those settings for this client, but I will go back and double-check again now.